# How can I get progress of a long task out of a function in my react/redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm currently trying to come up with a way of getting information out of a long running task (few seconds to a minute long) that occurs after uploading a file in my app. I am using react/redux and am currently trying this:

```
export const longTask = (file) => (dispatch) => {
    // setup file ready
    fileReader.onload = () => {
        let lastTime = Date.now();
        const lines = fileReader.result.split('\n');
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            const currentTime = Date.now();
            if (currentTime - lastTime >= 100) {
                dispatch(updateNumber(i / lines.length));
                lastTime = currentTime;
            }
            // Do long, intensive task for current line
        }
    }
}
```

which would operate inside of `redux-thunk`. The problem is though, that dispatch only queues the actions to run, it doesn't run them immediately and that this blocks the rendering of React as a whole. Does anyone have a pattern that would help with this sort of work? I don't really want to offload the work to a web-worker, since the work is constructing a data object that is quite large and transfering data to and from a web-worker is through value and not reference (implies data copying).

Edit: Note that I am using React v15.6.2, not v16.*, since it conflicts with Golden Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the problem is what you described you could rewrite the long task so that after some number of iterations you schedule the rest of the work e.g. with `setTimeout`.

Comment: I've thought about this and I think it's definitely an acceptable solution; I was just hoping that there would be a more elegant one out there. Will set as correct if I don't see anything better.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have a reducer that has a `state.longTask.queue` array in which you put all the lines, and then have a react component dispatch an action that only processes the next line in the queue. This would give control back to react where you can update the progress accordingly and you get a render cycle in between two lines being processed. No need for `setTimeout.`.